# Prove that $X$ is compact if and only if $D(A,B) > 0$ for any two closed disjoint subsets.

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. For any two $A$, $B$  $X$ we define
$D(A,B) = \inf_{x \in A, y \in B} d(x, y)$ .
Prove that $X$ is compact if and only if $D(A,B) > 0$ for any two closed disjoint subsets.

I was only able to prove compactness implies $D(A,B)>0$ but I'm having trouble proving the other side. Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other implication is false. Take the integers, with the usual distance.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/817502)

Comment: @Roby5 Sure it does provide and answer with a specific and easy to verify example. The question being about "the other side". i.e. the other direction, this counterexample is exactly what is needed.